# What is the difference between media print and media screen

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm working on a project and getting two types of media queries like this

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
        div.page {
            page-break-after: always !important;
            page-break-inside: avoid !important;
        }

    </style>
    <style media="screen,print">
        .customTdWidth {
            width: 35% !important;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .tdValue {
            width: 65%;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted black !important;
        }

    </style>
```

What is the difference between "screen" and "print" in media queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might sound daft or too obvious but:

`Screen = For Screens` `Print = For Print`

Media screen will basically style screens and media print will effectively work for printable pages.

([ref.1](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-difference-between-media-print-and-media-screen))

([ref.2](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp))

Comment: On the point. Good answer! And it's possible to combine the media queries with all kind of attributes like height, width ... They are commonly used for responsive designs or how hipsters say: PWA